# Get 4 Items from one Selection on Listview Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem, I have a list View lets call it ListView1, that is populated dynamically from local storage after a sync from Azure.

Now I am having a problem selecting and getting information from the item click.
I need to get four different types of information and pass it to a flyout when there is an item click on the listview.

```
//This is the way the List is Created
string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "my.db");

    public async void CreateList ()
    {
        await AzureWebService.Instance.InitLocalStoreAsync(DB_PATH);
        var t = await AzureWebService.Instance.GetListItems(); //GET THE OG LIST

        var list = new ObservableCollection<winMerchant>(); //create a new list of Names, (with the BitmapImage Field )

        foreach (var f in t)
        {
            var m = new winDirectory(); //give the customized merchant object, the same VALUES as the ACTUAL mercahnt object

            m.MyName1 = f.MyName1;
            m.MyName2 = f.MyName2;
            m.MyNumber = f.MyNumber; //int 
            m.MyPic = ImageHelper.Base64StringToBitmap(f.MyPic); //CUSTOM PART ==> Take the newly defined BitmapImage (wMyPic) and convert the Pic string into it

            list.Add(m); //add the new People into a list

        }
        MyList.ItemsSource = list;         
    }
```

And this is the xaml

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            <Image Source="{Binding wPic}" Width="75" Height="75" />

            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding wMyName1}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding wMyName2}" />

            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Helper Class

```
class winMerchant: Contacts
{
    public   BitmapImage wPic { get; set; }

    public int wMyNumber { get; set; }

    public string wMyName1 { get; set; }

    public string wMyName2 { get; set; }
}
```

The Number should be passed to a flyout on click... 
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just get the selected item's number from item click event of ListView.

```
private void MainListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.ClickedItem as winMerchant;
        int number = item.wMyNumber;
    }
```

Also make IsItemClickEnabled="True" of your Listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding wMyNumber}" to the <Image>
```

With this you can pass the number of the clicked object, in the c# (inside the click event) you can just create a List<> or an Array with data about your objects (so you can use this collection of object to display it in the flyout)